# How to do zero down time schema migrations for large tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, rds

I'm looking for a solution that is compatible with django + mysql/postgres to do online migrations. The best solution I've seen is [Large Hadron Migrator](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm), but LHM is a rails application and I would need to keep the ORMs in sync by hand, the second best tool I've looked at is [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html), but I'm not quite sure on how to integrate it with django's migration tool.

There are alternatives, like the tool [OnlineSchemaChange.php](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=430801045932&_fb_noscript=1) from facebook and [TableMigrator](https://github.com/freels/table_migrator) from twitter, but both seem inactive. I've also stumbled upon [oak](https://code.google.com/p/openarkkit/) but didn't really into it.

So, the question is, How can I make django migrations (1.7, not south) for large tables, that can potentially hog IO, without dowtime.

Comment: [This article](http://engineering.tilt.com/7-postgresql-data-migration-hacks/) has a solution for postgres

Comment: Also, [this is a nice presentation](http://russ.garrett.co.uk/talks/postgres-gds/) for zero-down-time migrations using postgres

Answer (score 0):

If that's on option: **Migrate your application to MySQL 5.6** - migrations are way less painless since MySQL 5.6 supports online DDL just like PostgreSQL and it will release you from many headaches migrating big tables.

Here's a list of what is possible: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html

For older versions of MySQL there's really no silver bullet that will do magic for you with South & Django, my advise is to Google for a migration pattern known as **Expand/Contract**.

I've used pt-online-schema-change with big success also on older MySQL 5.5/

Comment: thx for the answer. I'm already using 5.6.21, the problem is that add/drop column can be quite expensive for a handful of tables, expensive in the sense that the DML query will use all the IO from the server for a couple of minutes, degrading the performance of everything else, these tables are just a couple of GBs in size. The good thing about the migration tools is that they copy the data in blocks with delays between copies, not hogging the IO from the server (at least, that is what I expect).

Comment: Okay, I didn't suspect IO being the problem looking at original post... rather just downtime itself. And yes - pt-online-schema-change will slowly do the migration without hogging IO, you can even control the speed of it.

Comment: Reference: [Expand/Merge/Contract or Parallel Change](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ParallelChange.html)